# How to change device name used by Google Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I use the same Google account with Google Chrome on several devices including my Android phone. So, Google Chrome shows me tabs opened on other devices (ex: `chrome://history/`). Is there any way to change the name assigned for my Android device there?

See the following screen as example - I would like to change "Galaxy Nexus" to something else.

[image: list of devices: Work Macbook, Galaxy Nexus]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**As of 2019, the Android devices cannot be renamed; both from themselves and from other devices.**

The name listed on "Other devices" currently depends on the operating system:

1. Windows, macOS, and Linux use their hostname
2. Android possibly uses its [marketing name from Google Play's supported devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131)
3. Chrome OS use their product name (e.g. Chromebook, Chromebit)

However, renaming the device directly from the Chrome browser has not been implemented.

This was reported as [Issue #124964 in Chromium Bugs Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124964) since Apr 24, 2012, requesting a feature to allow devices in "Other devices" menu to be renamed. The report was branched into 2 separate issues:

- [Issue #455925](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=455925) for mobile UI
- [Issue #664647](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=664647) for desktop UI